# Show a legend for each panel in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given this data:

```
  mtcars %>%
     gather(-mpg, -hp, key = "var", value = "value") %>% 
  mtcars %>%
  gather(-mpg, -hp, key = "var", value = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = value, y = mpg, color = hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw()
```

As you can see, there is one legend for hp (which hide low values). I want a legend for each panel.

Comment: While this could be easily achieved by splitting your data and making use of e.g. `patchwork` you will get the same legend for each panel as the range of hp does not vary per panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stefan already mentioned in his comment we could use `patchwork` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(patchwork) 


mtcars_list <- mtcars %>%
  gather(-mpg, -hp, key = "var", value = "value") %>% 
  group_split(var)

gg_list = lapply(mtcars_list, function(x) {
  ggplot(x, aes(x = value, y = mpg, color = hp)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ var, scales = "free") +
    theme_bw()
})

# patchwork
wrap_plots(gg_list)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why in my plots, the panels are very small, but the legend is big.

Comment: Did you used the Zoom tab in Plots windows? essentially it is the same code!

Comment: I think bcs I have lots of panels. how Can I plot 6 out of the 9 from the list,

Comment: If I understand correctly: You could subset your list with `[1:6]` like: `gg_list = lapply(mtcars_list[1:6], ....`

Comment: or modify `wrap_plots()` with `ncol()` like: `# patchwork
wrap_plots(gg_list, ncol=2)`

Comment: Many thanks. last thing, please. Do you know how to reduce the white space between the panels and between the legend and the panels.

Comment: you can control the layout with `+ plot_layout(widths = c())`